# How to remove Vietnamese accent in URL when asking a new post?

Tags: url, question2answer

When asking a new Vietnamese question on my question2answer site, the newly created post will have the URL with the permalink created from title Vietnamese words - i.e. with Vietnamese accent.

That URL make it un-pretty when sharing the link as below snapshot.

I have turned on the option `Remove accents from question URLs` in `Admin - Viewing` configuration page but it doesn't help. How can I find a work-around for this?

[image]

The highlighted URL when copied will be

http://demo.question2answer.org/391/**c%C3%A2u-h%E1%BB%8Fi-c%E1%BB%A7a-tui**

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/25850/remove-accents-from-tag-url) on question2anser.org/qa, here is my resolution for this.

1. Edit file `<<q2aHOME>>\qa-include\util\string.php`
2. Add a new function *qa_convert_vi_to_en*

code:

```
function qa_convert_vi_to_en($str) 
{
    $str = preg_replace('/(à|á|?|?|ã|â|?|?|?|?|?|a|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'a', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(è|é|?|?|?|ê|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'e', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(ì|í|?|?|i)/', 'i', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(ò|ó|?|?|õ|ô|?|?|?|?|?|o|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'o', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(ù|ú|?|?|u|u|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'u', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(?|ý|?|?|?)/', 'y', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(d)/', 'd', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(À|Á|?|?|Ã|Â|?|?|?|?|?|A|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'A', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(È|É|?|?|?|Ê|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'E', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ì|Í|?|?|I)/', 'I', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ò|Ó|?|?|Õ|Ô|?|?|?|?|?|O|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'O', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ù|Ú|?|?|U|U|?|?|?|?|?)/', 'U', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(?|Ý|?|?|?)/', 'Y', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/(Ð)/', 'D', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

3. Update function `qa_string_remove_accents` to return with the newly created one.

code:

```
function qa_string_remove_accents($string)
/*
Return UTF-8 input $string with all accents (on Roman characters) removed
*/
{
    if (qa_to_override(__FUNCTION__)) { $args=func_get_args(); return qa_call_override(__FUNCTION__, $args); }

    //global $qa_utf8removeaccents;
    //return strtr($string, $qa_utf8removeaccents);

    return qa_convert_vi_to_en($string);
}
```

Comment: Same answer by me is also posted here http://www.question2answer.org/qa/6713/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls?show=38639#a38639